# Why my status bar icons are black and why can't I change it? (After Flutter 2.0 Upgrade)

Tags: flutter, dart

After I upgrade Flutter 2.0, the **color** of the **status bar's icon/text** changed from white to black. After I upgraded because I did not make any other changes. Now the status bar icons of **all apps** I run is black. Why?

[image]

**I tried the real device. Result is the same. So this is not an emulator problem.**

**Also not working** `Brightness.light`:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));
```

When I run this code, it turns white for a few seconds and then turns black again. Like here:

[image]

I wonder if people who have upgraded after Flutter 2.0 have the same problem?

**What is the reason for this and how to make white again?**

---

***Edit:** When I `flutter downgrade` it turns white. The problem seems to be with flutter upgrade to  2.0. But this time when I run* `statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark` *it goes black for a few seconds and turns white again. This code doesn't work at all. **So Flutter 2.0 is not the reason why I can't change it to white when it is black. But the reason it's black is flutter 2.0.***

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this issue as it happened with my project as well. The solution by @Tipu Sultan worked for me. Thanks for raising this question in StackOverFlow.

Comment: This is still and issue, any news on this ?

Comment: @ArtonBej  **status bar icons black**: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77502 => https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/75091  **statusBarIconBrightness not working**: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77887 => https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64001 .  So still open on both issues.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
MaterialApp(
      //...
      theme: ThemeData(
        //...
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      ),
      //...
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

it's a bug, I saw somebody created an issue on flutter repo

meanwhile this code does fix an issue:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
),
```

Comment: Which one is a bug? `statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark` not working or status bar icons turning black on Flutter 2.0 ?

Comment: status bar icons turning black on Flutter 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light)
```

Comment: it doesn't work just like `statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light`

Comment: hm... I am sorry that it didnt work for you. If you want you could take a look at the SafeArea Widget as well. Maybe it works then.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this. brightness: Brightness.dark;

```
AppBar(
  title: Text(widget.title),
  backgroundColor: Constants.appBarColor,
  brightness: Brightness.dark;
  centerTitle: false,
  elevation: 4.0,
);
```

So Brightness.dark makes status bar white.

Comment: That is depreciated with Flutter 2.5

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the new Flutter SDK 2.5, then use

`appBar: AppBar(systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,)`

instead of "brightness: Brightness.dark" as it was deprecated